How to Run Wordfeud Helper Apps on Ubuntu?
I enjoy playing Wordfeud and want to use a Wordfeud helper app to improve my gameplay. Many of these apps, like Beste Wordfeud Helper, are designed for Android. I want to run them on Ubuntu, but I’m encountering issues.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Using Anbox:

Installed Anbox following the instructions on their GitHub page.
Loaded the APK file using adb install.
The app appears to install, but it crashes immediately upon opening.


Using an Android Emulator (WayDroid):

Installed WayDroid, but when I try to launch the app, I get an error about "unsupported architecture" or a blank screen.


Alternative Approaches:

Tried running the app in a virtual machine (Android x86), but performance is extremely slow, and the app doesn't work properly.



I’m running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with the following specs:

Processor: Intel i5-7200U
RAM: 8GB
GPU: Integrated Intel Graphics

Has anyone successfully run Wordfeud helper apps on Ubuntu? Are there better tools for running Android apps, or is there a Linux-native solution?
Thanks in advance for your help!

You want to install it on a linux machine so you could also just use something like https://www.wordfeud-helper.com/
